# SQLLite update doesn't update the table at all (Android Studio with Kotlin)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, sql-update, android-sqlite

I'm fairly new to Android, Kotlin, and SQLLite.

I have this table creation.

```
val create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME (" +
    "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "$COLUMN_USERNAME STRING, $COLUMN_PASSWORD STRING, $COLUMN_EMAIL STRING, $COLUMN_LAST_LOGIN DATETIME NULL, " +
    "$COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST BOOLEAN, $COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST BOOLEAN, $COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT BOOLEAN, " +
    "$COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE BOOLEAN" +
    ")"
db.execSQL(create)
```

I can successfully add new data with this:

```
val values = ContentValues()

values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, "admin")
values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, "password")
values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, "test@test.com")
values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST, true)
values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST, true)
values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT, true)
values.put(COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE, admin.isActive)

val db = this.writableDatabase
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
```

I also can successfully retrieve data with this:

```
val db = this.readableDatabase
val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME", null)
```

by which I get the info that the data I put there has the ID = 1

But I cannot change the data into something else, either with this code:

```
val values = ContentValues()

values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, "adminssss")
values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, "passwordsss")
values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, "test@test.org")
values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST, false)
values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST, true)
values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT, false)
values.put(COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE, true)

val db = this.writableDatabase
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COLUMN_ID=1", arrayOf())
// or
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COLUMN_ID=?", arrayOf("1"))
```

Or

```
val db = this.writableDatabase
val query = "UPDATE $TABLE_NAME " +
    "SET $COLUMN_USERNAME = 'adminssss', $COLUMN_PASSWORD = 'passwordsss', $COLUMN_EMAIL = 'test@test.org', " +
    "$COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST = 0, " +
    "$COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST = 1, " +
    "$COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT = 0, " +
    "$COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE = 1 " +
    "WHERE $COLUMN_ID = 1"
db.rawQuery(query, null)
// or
db.execQuery(query)
```

I'm not too strong with query language, but I've tried to double check the query and can't found anything wrong with it. When the update query is run, which ever version it is from above example, all can run without error, but when I re-select the data again, nothing is changed. The data stays the same like the original first time I put them in.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Use `var cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME", null)` instead of val and try.

Comment: @Jaymin it's the same. the cursor went to be processed on another function to extract the data and put it into array of model class, and the cursor is reassigned to var. I can retrieve multiple rows correctly.

Comment: Can you replace, `db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COLUMN_ID=1", arrayOf())` by 
`db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "${COLUMN_ID} = 1", arrayOf())`

Comment: if you want to use a database in Android, I highly recommend using RoomDB, its much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your first update code (both work), it works (see Working example below).

I suspect that you issue might be that you have deleted a row and the added another row. In such a case, because you have AUTOINCREMENT coded such a row would not have an ID as 1 but perhaps two.

- You could check the underlying rows by using the logAll function (as used in the Working Example below).

If using the code from the working example then the issues in attempting to use rawQuery and execQuery become moot.

I believe that your issue is how you are viewing the result (or is as previously explained). Consider the following working example :-

## Working Example

The Database Helper class, **DBHelper.kt** (based upon the available code) including the code, such as update as functions :-

```
class DBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION) {

    val all: Cursor
        get() = this.writableDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null)

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " STRING, " +
                COLUMN_PASSWORD + " STRING, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " STRING, " +
                COLUMN_LAST_LOGIN + " DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST + " BOOLEAN, " +
                COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST + " BOOLEAN," +
                COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT + " BOOLEAN, " +
                COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE + " BOOLEAN" +
                ")"
        )
    }

    fun add(
            username: String,
            password: String,
            email: String,
            privaccessadminlist: Boolean,
            privchangeadminlist: Boolean,
            privsendemailreport: Boolean,
            is_active: Boolean): Long {

        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, password)
        cv.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST, privaccessadminlist)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST, privchangeadminlist)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT, privsendemailreport)
        return this.writableDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)
    }

    fun logAll() {
        val csr = all
        var sb = StringBuilder()
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            sb = StringBuilder().append("Row is " + csr.position.toString())
            sb.append("\n\tUserName is :").append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)))
            sb.append("\n\tPasword is :").append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD)))
            sb.append("\n\tEmail is :").append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAIL)))
            sb.append("\n\t PRIVACCESSAL is ").append((csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST)) > 0).toString())
            sb.append("\n\t PRIVCHGAL is ").append((csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST)) > 0).toString())
            sb.append("\n\t PRIVSNDEMAIL is ").append((csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT)) > 0).toString())
            Log.d("LOGDATA", sb.toString())
        }
    }

    // Suggested update code
    fun updateById(id: Long,
                   username: String,
                   password: String,
                   email: String,
                   privaccessadminlist: Boolean,
                   privchangeadminlist: Boolean,
                   privsendemailreport: Boolean,
                   is_active: Boolean): Int {
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, password)
        cv.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST, privaccessadminlist)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST, privchangeadminlist)
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT, privsendemailreport)
        val whereclause = "$COLUMN_ID=?"
        val whereargs = arrayOf(id.toString())
        return this.writableDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, whereclause, whereargs)
    }

    //Your code
    fun update() {
        val values = ContentValues()

        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, "adminszzz")
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, "passwordzzz")
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, "test@test.orgzzz")
        values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST, false)
        values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST, true)
        values.put(COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT, false)
        values.put(COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE, true)

        val db = this.writableDatabase
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COLUMN_ID=1", arrayOf())
// or
        //db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COLUMN_ID=?", arrayOf("1"))
    }


    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    }

    companion object {

        val DBNAME = "mydb"
        val DBVERSION = 1

        val TABLE_NAME = "mytable"
        val COLUMN_ID = BaseColumns._ID
        val COLUMN_USERNAME = "username"
        val COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password"
        val COLUMN_EMAIL = "email"
        val COLUMN_LAST_LOGIN = "last_login"
        val COLUMN_PRIV_ACCESS_ADMIN_LIST = "priv_access_admin_list"
        val COLUMN_PRIV_CHANGE_ADMIN_LIST = "priv_change_admin_list"
        val COLUMN_PRIV_SEND_EMAIL_REPORT = "priv_send_email_report"
        val COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE = "is_active"
    }
}
```

And an Activity to invoke the functions **MainAvctivity.kt** :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var dbhlpr = DBHelper(this)

        dbhlpr = DBHelper(this)
        dbhlpr.add("admin", "password", "test@test.com", true, true, true, true)
        dbhlpr.logAll()

        dbhlpr.updateById(1, "adminssss", "passwordsss", "test@test.org", false, true, false, true)
        dbhlpr.logAll()

        dbhlpr.update();
        dbhlpr.logAll();
    }
}
```

## Result

When run the following is output to the log :-

```
2019-05-17 16:12:07.182 18164-18164/aso.so56179532update D/LOGDATA: Row is 0
        UserName is :admin
        Pasword is :password
        Email is :test@test.com
         PRIVACCESSAL is true
         PRIVCHGAL is true
         PRIVSNDEMAIL is true
2019-05-17 16:12:07.184 18164-18164/aso.so56179532update D/LOGDATA: Row is 0
        UserName is :adminssss
        Pasword is :passwordsss
        Email is :test@test.org
         PRIVACCESSAL is false
         PRIVCHGAL is true
         PRIVSNDEMAIL is false
2019-05-17 16:12:07.186 18164-18164/aso.so56179532update D/LOGDATA: Row is 0
        UserName is :adminszzz
        Pasword is :passwordzzz
        Email is :test@test.orgzzz
         PRIVACCESSAL is false
         PRIVCHGAL is true
         PRIVSNDEMAIL is false
```

i.e. There are 3 lots, each showing the single row from the database. The second two show that the data has been updated accordingly.

Comment: The code actually an "evaluated" version of the original code, which contains variables and models. But the value and generated SQL is true as what I've put on the code. Strangely, the code that you put together indeed working when I tried on fresh project, but not working when put inside that existing project. I guess there's something else going on here with my database settings or project settings, but I don't know what. The solution that I ultimately going for is to actually delete the row with that id, and create anew with the same id.

Comment: @ChenLiYong I suspect that the issue is that you've deleted a row or rows. AUTOINCREMENT maintains the highest value that has been used for the ID column. This if the first row has been deleted at some time then the ID will not be 1. I've tried explaining this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't closed the database by calling db.close() method after updating operation.

Closing the connection flushes the changes you've made, otherwise, the engine waits for the flush period before doing it. It's a good idea to close the connection when you're done using it to ensure that your changes actually go to the store. A power loss after a write and before a flush will lose data.